# tertiary characteristic class: integration of the Chern-Simons form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, characteristic-classes, gauge-theory, chern-classes, chern-simons-theory

Let $P \to M$ be a trivial principal circle bundle with connection $A$ over a closed 3-manifold $M$. The Chern-Simons 3-form of the connection is defined by $\mathrm{CS}(A) = A \wedge dA$. Suppose that the integral $\int_M \mathrm{CS}(A)$ is an integer. Then $\mathrm{CS}(A)$ is a closed 3-form with integral periods and thus is the curvature of a [circle 2-bundle with connection](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/circle+n-bundle+with+connection) or, equivalently, of a U(1)-bundle gerbe with connection. Is this 2-bundle/gerbe discussed somewhere in the literature? Is there an "explicit" (whatever this may mean) construction of it?

Moreover, can we view this 2-bundle/gerbe as a tertiary characteristic class? The usual characteristic classes vanish in this setting:

- The bundle is trivial and thus the Chern class vanishes.
- The [Chern-Simons 3-bundle](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+Chern-Simons+line+3-bundle) (constucted as the "square" of $[P,A]$ in differential cohomology) vanishes in differential cohomology since its holonomy is given by $X \mapsto \exp \int_X \mathrm{CS}(A)$ for every 3-cycle $X \in Z_3(M, \mathbb{Z})$ and the Chern-Simons form was assumed to have integral periods.

Comment: I'd start by checking Urs Schreiber's work.